# Restore damaged folder inodes in ddrescue image

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, inode, ddrescue

I restored my failing external ntfs hdd using ddrescue, around 80% of the data is restored, the rest seems to be bad blocks. I can mount the created image file and ubuntu detects it and shows the filesystem. I used ddru_ntfsfindbad to get a list of all files on the drive and all files/inodes on the drive which contain bad blocks. The mft seems to be fine.

The problem is that some folder inodes contain bad blocks, thus when i open those folders "files" shows the folder empty and ls returns `ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error`.

Is there any tool/way to repair the folder inodes to link them up with the corresponding files again?

In the output of ddru_ntfsfindbad i have information on the files in those corrupted folders, e.g. all files and folders that are in the corrupted folders and the inodes and disk position of all those files.

Thanks already.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/427199/1178017

Comment: Ubuntus ntfsfix tells me everything is fine. Testdisk doesn't fix anything and tells me the mft and backup mft are fine. In windows the hdd is not detected at all or immediately ejected again. I can't mount the image file as windows tells me "the disc image is corrupted" and chkdsk on the image file tells me "the drive, path, or file name is not valid".